# VIsual studio hanging on BSC creation

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2012, freeze

Visual Studio, as of late, has been taking a long time (roughly 7-10 minutes on a complete rebuild) generating a .bsc file for the executable it is building.

The executable has already been built (it only takes about a minute), but alas it won't run/debug it until this BSC file is created fully.

What is it, why is it taking so long, and is there any possibility of doing without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BSC file can be disabled by going to Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Browse Information -> set *"Enable Browse Information"* to **No**.